# My three.js Raycaster is not working properly. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, three.js

After I created a new `three.js` project, I added a `Raycaster` from the `three.js` documentation and "attached" a cube to it. The idea is that the cube moves to the position of the cursor but my cube moves way too much to the sides.

Here is my code:

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import {MeshBasicMaterial} from "three";

const canvas = document.querySelector('#c')
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, canvas})
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 2, 0.1, 1000)
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
controls.addEventListener('change', camera)
camera.position.z = 3.5;
camera.position.x = 3.5;
camera.position.y = 5;
camera.lookAt(-0.5,-0.5,-0.5)
controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5)

const scene = new THREE.Scene()
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x36393e)
const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader()
let rollOverMaterial, rollOverMesh, line;
let planes = [];
const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
const pointer = new THREE.Vector3()

init()
render()

function init() {

    const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(16, 16, 0xffffff)
    scene.add(gridHelper)
    gridHelper.position.y = -0.5
    gridHelper.position.x = -0.5
    gridHelper.position.z = -0.5

    const rollOverGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 0.999, 1 );
    rollOverMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0077be, opacity: 0.5, transparent: true } );
    rollOverMesh = new THREE.Mesh( rollOverGeo, rollOverMaterial );
    const edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(rollOverGeo)
    line = new THREE.LineSegments(edges, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0x6b6b6b}))

    scene.add( rollOverMesh, line );

    const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(16, 16)
    planeGeometry.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2 );

    const plane = new THREE.Mesh( planeGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { visible: false } ) );
    scene.add( plane );
    plane.position.x = -0.5
    plane.position.y = -1.5
    plane.position.z = -0.5
    planes.push(plane)

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    document.addEventListener( 'pointermove', onMouseMove );

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );
}

function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    render();

}

function onMouseMove( event ) {

    pointer.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    pointer.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;
    pointer.z = 1;
    let mouse = [event.clientX, event.clientY];
    raycaster.setFromCamera(pointer, camera);
    let intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(planes, true);

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

        const intersect = intersects[ 0 ];

        rollOverMesh.position.copy( intersect.point ).add( intersect.face.normal );
        rollOverMesh.position.y += 0.5
        line.position.copy( intersect.point ).add( intersect.face.normal );
        line.position.y += 0.5

        render();

    }

}

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
    requestAnimationFrame(render)
}
```

I tried to change it to `event.pageX` instead of `event.clientX` and expected it to work but it didn't. I'm new to JS and `three.js` so if I'm just being dumb then I'm sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think I solved this. The first thing I did was remove two of the times you called `render`, as it caused lag (in the onMouseMove and onWindowResize functions). The next thing I did was I looked at the plane mesh and I removed its offsets, as this was a part of the cubes offset when you moved the mouse. After that I changed these lines: `rollOverMesh.position.y += 0.5` and `line.position.y += 0.5` by changing the offset to -1. I also changed pointer.z to 0, but I do not know if that did anything. The last thing I did was add this line right after you create the rollOverGeo variable: `rollOverGeo.translate(-.2, 0, -.2)`. This made the mouse more in the center of the cube.
Here is the fixed code:

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { MeshBasicMaterial } from "three";

const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, canvas })
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 2, 0.1, 1000)
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
controls.addEventListener('change', camera)
camera.position.z = 3.5;
camera.position.x = 3.5;
camera.position.y = 5;
camera.lookAt(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5)
controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5)

const scene = new THREE.Scene()
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x36393e)
const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader()
let rollOverMaterial, rollOverMesh, line;
let planes = [];
const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
const pointer = new THREE.Vector3()

init()
render()

function init() {

    const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(16, 16, 0xffffff)
    scene.add(gridHelper)
    gridHelper.position.y = -0.5
    gridHelper.position.x = -0.5
    gridHelper.position.z = -0.5

    const rollOverGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 0.999, 1);
    rollOverGeo.translate(-.2, 0, -.2)
    rollOverMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0077be, opacity: 0.5, transparent: true });
    rollOverMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rollOverGeo, rollOverMaterial);
    const edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(rollOverGeo)
    line = new THREE.LineSegments(edges, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x6b6b6b }))

    scene.add(rollOverMesh, line);

    const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(16, 16)
    planeGeometry.rotateX(- Math.PI / 2);

    const plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ visible: false }));
    scene.add(plane);
    plane.position.x = 0
    plane.position.y = 0
    plane.position.z = 0
    planes.push(plane)

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    //document.addEventListener('pointermove', onMouseMove);
    document.onmousemove = onMouseMove;
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);
}

function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    //render();

}

function onMouseMove(event) {

    pointer.x = (event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
    pointer.y = - (event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;
    pointer.z = 0;
    let mouse = [event.clientX, event.clientY];
    raycaster.setFromCamera(pointer, camera);
    let intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(planes, true);

    if (intersects.length > 0) {

        const intersect = intersects[0];

        rollOverMesh.position.copy(intersect.point).add(intersect.face.normal);
        rollOverMesh.position.y -= 1
        line.position.copy(intersect.point).add(intersect.face.normal);
        line.position.y -= 1

        //render();

    }

}
function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
    requestAnimationFrame(render)
}
```